# How do I remove duplicate rows in Python? One row is the original order other is refund value, I want to remove both from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I want to delete the duplicate row in case the immediate value is a negative number. Not delete the Id if it is repeating in the data frame

| Id | OrderID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 1 |
| A | 345 | -1 |
| C | 789 | 2 |
| C | 506 | 9 |
| D | 453 | 3 |
| E | 766 | 3 |
| E | 876 | -3 |
| E | 456 | 4 |
| E | 577 | 8 |

Result

| Id | OrderID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 789 | 2 |
| C | 506 | 9 |
| D | 453 | 3 |
| E | 456 | 4 |
| E | 577 | 8 |

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will help with your problem statement

```
df_array = df.values
drop_values = []

for i in range(len(df1)):
  if(i+1 == len(df1)):
    break;
  if(df_array[i][0] == df_array[i+1][0]):
    if(df_array[i+1][1] < 0):
      drop_values.append(df1.index[i])
      drop_values.append(df1.index[i+1])

df = df.drop(drop_values)
```

Output:
initial dataframe
[image]

the result after deleting immediate next negative value 
[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. my goal is to remove rows only in case the value corresponding to that is negative. I'm thinking your solution might remove all duplicate rows with that ID and keep only one.

Comment: let me understand your question, can you tell me the expected output for this data frame
`df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Id": ['A','A','A','B','B','C','D','B'],
    'value': [1,-1,1,3,-2, 3, 4, -2]
})`

Comment: Ok so the dataframe has first value as a Transaction and the next immediate value is the same amount but a refund. Since it is a negative value. So in this case : "A" is the transaction Id and "1" is the transaction amount. Now "-1" has the same transaction Id "A" and has a refund "-1". Therefore, I'd want to delete both the rows. But incase it was "A" : "1" and B: "-2" . I'll not do anything. Only in a case where negative amt is immediately after the row. I hope I could explain it better. I'll make some changes to my question, thanks Chethan.

Comment: edited with new answer check it out, hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach. So first count the number of each Id in the row 'Id', store these in a list and add it to the data frame. Now you can easily filter on the number of Id, so in your case filter on number==1. Hope this might help.

```
number = []
for i in df['A']:
  a = len(df[df['A']==i])
  number.append(a)
df['number'] = number

df_new = df[df['number']==1]
df_new
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I want to remove only row with a corresponding negative value. For example there might my ID A with a value of 3 somewhere which I do not want to remove. Just rows where ID A has value 1 and is immediately followed by a row with same ID and same value but negative ( ID A and value -1) Hope I'm making sense